# Java Random class execution for printing a six digit number only

Tags: java, random

I want to generate a six-digit random number everytime.
I am using

```
public class Test {
    static Random rand = new Random();

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(1000000);
        System.out.println(rand_int1);
```

Will it print the six-digit number or it can print any number between 0 to 1000000.
I executed and got a 6 digit number but just want to be sure
Can it give 1 or 2 or 3 digit number also?

Comment: Depends what you mean by a "6 digit number". Is "0" a six digit number, just missing the leading zeros when you print it? Or do you mean it starts with 1-9, followed by 5 0-9 digits? If the latter, you need to generate a number between 100000 and 1000000.

Comment: You could very easily test this yourself, and see that it produces numbers with less than six digits. I ran it a few thousand times by wrapping it in a loop and among others I got numbers like 6642, 40328, etc.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper you'd surely only need to run it a few times: I'd expect a non-6 digit number about 10% of the time.

Comment: @Andy Turner yes i need the latter one between 100000 and 999999.How can i get that?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah, I know. It's just the value I put in the loop. Could have been in the hundreds and still produce a few of those easily.

Comment: @Johnson see one of the 90 answers in the duplicate.

Comment: Yes just checked


  int min =100000;
  int max = 999999;
  int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
  
  System.out.println(randomNum);

This works